# Save Depth camera recording

Tags: c++, opencv, save, openni

I have recently purchased an Orbbec Astra camera, which uses the same technology and produces the same style depth map as a Microsoft Kinect.

What would be the correct file format to save the depth map frames, How would I go about saving the videos recorded?

I have been able to load a stream but am not sure what format the frames should be saved in so that i can load them for testing at a later stage and still have all the same information.

I am using OpenNI2, OpenCV3.1.0 and C++.

Comment: who will use those files? I've saved kinect frames just as raw data, since resolution is fixed. Others save them as 16 bit single channel png...

Comment: I will be using the saved frames. I need to mount the camera in a position that will make development hard if I have to have it plugged in and recreate the video each time. So I just want to record it once and then load the video when i want to test something new